# search a particular record in table view controller iOS swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am fetching data from url using jsonserialization method and stores each and every record in an object of a class and displays each record in table vc.

Now I want to implement search using search bar and watch many tutorials which had comparison between array of string type and another array of string type(Hardcoded values in array).
But according to my need, my data is store in class obj not hardcoded data and data from that object is displayed on cellforrow.
cellforrow contains.

```
if isSearching 
{
    cell.textLabel?.text = searchArray[indexPath.row] //.compName

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = searchArray[indexPath.row]
}
else{ 
    cell.textLabel?.text = tempArray[indexPath.row].compName

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = tempArray[indexPath.row].complocation
}
return cell
```

So how to implement search bar,  getting following error.
kindly help!
here my classname is -> comp.
and searchArray is array of strings and
 tempArray is array which contains class obj

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFSyr.png)

Comment: You have to let us know what your type `comp` is...? So add class definition or something of `comp`

Comment: Hello @Ladislav comp is my class name..class comp {

    var compName : String! }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. here's it is
following is change in else condition

```
searchArr   = tempArray.filter { $0.<classAttribute>.contains(searchText) }

searchArray = searchArr as! [comp]

print("search match")

listTableView.reloadData()
```

here searchArr and searchArray and tempArray are array of class type, &
classAttribute is ATTRIBUTE of that class that you want to search in tableview, my class name is "comp"

Answer (score 0):

Then you just have to modify search filter you use to be:

```
searchArray = tempArray.filter({$0.compName == searchBarClicked.text!})
```

Compiler was telling you that you cannot compare `$0` which is of type `comp` to `searchBarClicked.text` which is `String`, so `$0.compName` will be `String` and thus `==` can be used

Comment: I have tried it but other error is generated on .filter, saying -> Cannot assign value of type '[comp]' to type '[String]'...

Comment: Please add your `comp` class above to your question and an example what data is in `tempArray`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
searchArray = searchArray.filter{(($0["name"]?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(textField.text!)))!}
```